# Razor ASP.NET Core - datetimes from date picker not returning in the model

Tags: .net-core, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using dotnet core v4 and Bootstrap 5. The datetime picker I'm using is Tempus Dominus which I'm including in my `_layout` like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
```

My model includes the field

```
public DateTime StoveInstalled { get; set; }
```

The form in my view includes

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.StoveInstalled, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "txtStoveInstalledDate" })
```

With the following in a script tag for the datetime picker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(txtStoveInstalledDate).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            language: "tr"
        });
    });
</script>
```

The textbox is getting populated where there is a value, so the model is working and razor is populating the field.

Returning to a controller looking like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CustomerViewModel customer)
{
    return View();
}
```

However the date return looking like this, whether edited or not

[image: Value returned]

The datetime picker works and updates the TextBoxFor value. I can get the data back by not using a form and just submitting everything on a button press with AJAX, but it's a big form and that's frankly ugly, plus I would like to understand what the issue is.

One obvious looking thing is the readonly attribute, I've added that as I only want the date picker to be able to edit the textbox. This works well.  If I remove the readonly, the value returned is still the default minimum datetime value.

Somebody stated there is no dotnet core V4, fair enough, I took that from the following reference, I just went with one of the standard project starters in visual studio.
[image: Version info]
I have no idea how to tell what version I'm actually using, but in the project properties is says target Framework .Net Framework 4.8, so maybe this is not core. I think the issue is still the same one though?
I add the rest of my includes in here, in case it's something odd with the order I'm adding them.

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Let's sweep!</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" integrity="sha512-DedNBWPF0hLGUPNbCYfj8qjlEnNE92Fqn7xd3Sscfu7ipy7Zu33unHdugqRD3c4Vj7/yLv+slqZhMls/4Oc7Zg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance, hopefully!

Jim

Comment: There is no "dotnet core v4" .... 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 5.0, 6.0, and soon 7.0 .-take your pick

Comment: There's no date picker in what you posted, or an attempt to apply a date picker script to that input. This `@Html.TextBoxFor` will generate an `<input type="text'>`, not an `<input type="date">`. Whatever text was entered in that text box couldn't be parsed as a date.

Comment: Fair comments, Question updated!  I think this is more of a razor/MVC thing and the core stuff is a red herring!